# How to sync Gradle/Android versionCode between build server and workstation

Tags: android, gradle, continuous-integration, bamboo, build-server

Currently we have Bamboo listening to a Git repository on any changes. When a change occur the build process starts and increases the (Bamboo) build number by one.

I thought it would be nice to use this same build number for the Android project (versionCode) so that the user of the app can always refer to the actual build he/she received. This way the build number goes from 1 to 2 on the build server. Only the workstation doesn't know about this and still uses version 1.

Is there any way to sync this build number?

*Tried:*
*One possible solution a friend of mine suggested was to use a git command to get the commit number: `git rev-list HEAD --count` which is awesome. The only downside of this is that you cannot properly change build number within Bamboo. So the build number of Bamboo should be leading.*

Btw, I'm using Android Studio with Gradle

Answer (score 0):

Bamboo can be configured to set the `versionCode` value in the manifest to the build number when building, so propagating this change back to where the development is happening should be unnecessary.  To configure Bamboo to do this, add a Script task to the build plan (before the actual build task) with a body of:

```
sed -i 's/android:versionCode="[[﻿﻿:digit:]]*"/android:versionCode="${bamboo.buildNumber}"/' AndroidManifest.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is quite easy with gradle. You have to retrieve the latest build result in the gradle script and put it in the versionCode.

Here it is what you need (remember to change the variables to refer your server):

```
def getBambooNumber(){
    def url = "https://bambooServer:bambooPort/rest/api/latest/result/PROJECT-BAMBOO-ID/latest.json?os_authType=basic".toURL()
    def authValue = "USER:PASSWORD".bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
    def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(url.getText(requestProperties : ["Authorization" : "Basic " + authValue]))
    return json.buildNumber + 1 // +1 to Get the new build number
}


def bambooBuild = bambooBuildNumber()

android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        versionCode bambooBuild
        //This allows you to access in BuildConfig to the bamboo build
        buildConfigField "Integer", "BAMBOO_BUILD", "${bambooBuild}"
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.